# Styling richtextbox in windows phone 7 from code

Tags: windows-phone-7, richtextbox

So I want to style richtextbox text from code, but I don't know how. There are two variables in the text, and I want the second one to have the accentcolor, and 2pt bigger fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) site you can find out all the different properties the RichTextBox has.

Some stuff of interest

- FontFamily
- FontSize
- Font Style
- Foreground
- Background

Comment: Thanks! However when i want to use the accentbrush it says: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Media.Brush'"

Comment: Right....You can only give it what it wants. If you want to give it a string you have to use a converter. if you want a simple brush you cna give it something like: Brushes.Red;

Answer (score 0):

One way is to do it as in the below code

```
        Run r1 = new Run();
        r1.Text = "this is through ";
        r1.FontSize = 18.0;
        r1.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
        //r.Foreground=Brush.

        Run r2 = new Run();
        r2.Text = "code";
        r2.FontWeight = FontWeights.ExtraBold;
        r2.Foreground= new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();


        p.Inlines.Add(r1);
        p.Inlines.Add(r2);


        richTextBox1.Blocks.Add(p);
```